# How to print a reStructuredText node tree?

Tags: python, restructuredtext, docutils

Section [Parsing the Document](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/dev/hacking.html#parsing-the-document) of The [Docutils Hacker's Guide](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/dev/hacking.html) mentions the `quicktest.py` utility that can be used to print a node tree representation of a parsed [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) document. However I can't find `quicktest.py` anywhere in my docutils distribution installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils`. Is there other way to print the document tree?

Comment: The quicktest.py script is included in the latest snapshot tarball from http://docutils.sourceforge.net/. But it does not get installed when you install docutils (run setup.py). I don't know why. Anyway, the source is here: https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/docutils/tools/quicktest.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @mzjn the `quicktest.py` script is available at https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/docutils/tools/quicktest.py

A document tree can also be printed as follows:

```
from docutils.core import publish_string
print publish_string(rst)
```

where `rst` is a string containing reStructuredText to be processed.

Comment: To print an already existing document tree (maybe with custom transformations or extensions), the solution is `docutils.core.publish_from_doctree()`.